# Failed to create wallet for ton with Fift?

Tags: telegram

Right now I'm trying to create wallet for TON.

I downloaded and built Fift interpreter an was trying to create new wallet with: ./crypto/fift new-walelt.fif

```
 [ 1][t 0][1559491459.312618017][fift-main.cpp:147] Error interpreting standard preamble file `Fift.fif`: cannot locate file `Fift.fif`
 Check that correct include path is set by -I or by FIFTPATH environment variable, or disable standard preamble by -n.
```

Although my path variable is set. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, locate *{{lite-client-source-direcotry}}/crypto/fift*

This is **not** the build directory, that's the directory where are the source files (lite-client that you downloaded). So verify you have that it contains Fift.fif file.

If you installed it in the user working directory, it should be:

```
~/lite-client/crypto/fift/
```

Now, you should either set FIFTPATH variable to point to this directory or run fift with -I option:

```
export FIFTPATH=~/lite-client/crypto/fift/
./crypto/fift new-walelt.fif
```

Or

```
./crypto/fift -I~/lite-client/crypto/fift/ new-walelt.fif
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `./crypto/fift -I<source-directory>/crypto/fift new-wallet.fif` instead of setting environment variable? Are Fift.fif and Asm.fif library files inside FIFTPATH?

Make sure you have followed all the instruction written here:

https://test.ton.org/HOWTO.txt

It should work if you do all the above instruction correctly. If not, it might be a bug. Remember that TON is in a very early beta strage. You can submit the issue here:

https://github.com/copperbits/TON/issues

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this:

```
cd ~/liteclient-build
crypto/fift -I/root/lite-client/crypto/fift/lib -s /root/lite-client/crypto/smartcont/new-wallet.fif -1 wallet_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (worked for me)

```
export FIFTPATH=~/lite-client/crypto/fift/lib

./crypto/fift new-wallet.fif
```